# Incoming Pusher message crashes Visual Studio 2015 - There was an error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d)

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, visual-studio, pusher

I'm using Pusher to communicate between a web API and a website. After receiving the message Visual Studio crashes, if I'm debugging using Internet Explorer 11. When debugging in Chrome it's fine.

Example message:

> "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"

I'm sending the message like this:

```
var myMessage = LZString.compressToBase64(myJsonObject);
var pusher = new Pusher(appId, appKey, appSecret, new PusherOptions { Encrypted = true, Cluster = cluster });
pusher.Trigger(channel, event, myMessage);
```

and receiving like this:

```
var pusher = new Pusher(AppKey, {
    authEndpoint: myAuthEndPointUrl,
    cluster: cluster,
    encrypted: true
});

var myChannel = pusher.subscribe(channel);
myChannel.bind(event, function (data) {
    debugger;
});
```

After receiving the message Visual Studio crashes, with the following error in the Event Log:

```
Error Handler Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d). ---> System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d). ---> System.IO.PipeException: There was an error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d).
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.OnAsyncReadComplete(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 numBytes)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.EndRead()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, Message& message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext) \r\n    at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, Message& message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
```

and

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.25420.1, time stamp: 0x57685d85 
Faulting module name: VSDebugEng.dll, version: 14.0.25425.1, time stamp: 0x57982cbc 
Exception code: 0xc0000005 
Fault offset: 0x0013a451 
Faulting process id: 0x61d8 
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1f69bcfb8674e 
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe 
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\VSDebugEng.dll 
Report Id: a1d4427d-628f-11e6-a31a-989096d32e69
```